# vuex store not refresh computed property

Tags: vuex

Following the tutorial at this web address http://stackabuse.com/single-page-apps-with-vue-js-and-flask-state-management-with-vuex/, I encountered a problem that the function in the computed property was not automatically invoked after the state in the store was changed. The relevant code is listed as following:

Survey.vue

```js
computed: {
    surveyComplete() {
      if (this.survey.questions) {
        const numQuestions = this.survey.questions.length
        const numCompleted = this.survey.questions.filter(q =>q.choice).length
        return numQuestions === numCompleted
    }
    return false
    },
    survey() {
      return this.$store.state.currentSurvey
    },
    selectedChoice: {
      get() {
        const question = this.survey.questions[this.currentQuestion]
        return question.choice
      },
      set(value) {
        const question = this.survey.questions[this.currentQuestion]
        this.$store.commit('setChoice', { questionId: question.id, choice: value })
      }
    }
  }
```

When a radio button in the survey questions is chosen, selectedChoice will change the state in the store. However surveyComplete method was not called simultaneously. What's the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

surveyComplete() method does not 'spy' your store, it will be updated, when you change this.survey.questions only. So if you modify the store, nothing will happen inside surveyComplete. You may use the store inside the method.